# Como seleccionar todas las filas mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

necesito que se me muestren todos los movimientos que se registran en la tabla movimientos, pero solo se me muestran los movimientos del IdMovimiento 1.
A ver si alguien me puede corregir el código porfa.

```
$c=conectarBdteisbank();
$dnicookie=(@$_COOKIE[dnicookie]);
    
$cuenta=mysqli_query($c,"select IdCuenta from cuenta WHERE DNIC='$dnicookie'"); 
$fila1 = mysqli_fetch_array($cuenta);
$p1=$fila1['IdCuenta'];
$movimientos=mysqli_query($c,"select * from movimientos WHERE IdCuentaM='$p1'"); 
    echo mysqli_error($c);
    

  while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($movimientos)) 
  {
 $tipo=$fila['tipo'];
 $fecha=$fila['fecha'];
 $cantidad=$fila['cantidad'];
 $IdCuentaM=$fila['IdCuentaM'];

echo "<h3>Tipo: $tipo en la cuenta numero $IdCuentaM de $cantidad euros el dia $fecha</h3>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te está mostrando tres filas, porque la consulta tiene un `WHERE` que filtra los datos, si quieres todas las filas tienes que quitar ese `WHERE`, algo así: `$movimientos=mysqli_query($c,"select * from movimientos");`

Comment: La captura de pantalla muestra la consulta que necesitas, el WHERE es para restringir la consulta, si quieres todos los registros quita el WHERE "SELECT * FROM table_name" devuelve todos los registros

Comment: muchas gracias a los dos, ya lo he solucionado, estaba reciclando código antigüo y no me había fijado en ese detalle.

Comment: Dicho eso, si quieres todos los movimientos, esta consulta previa no tiene sentido: `$cuenta=mysqli_query($c,"select IdCuenta from cuenta WHERE DNIC='$dnicookie'");` y si quisieras datos relacionados en algún momento, puedes unir ambas tablas mediante `JOIN` sin necesidad de hacer dos consultas. Y, usa consultas preparadas cuando la SQL lleve datos que provienen de fuentes externas, de lo contrario tu código queda expuesto a ser atacado por hackers.